# Xrandr on osx not recognising screens

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, xrandr

in relation to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91174/horizonally-flip-osxs-monitor-output),  I'm using the xrandr command in osx to perform operations on my external monitors.  Unfortunately it does not appear to be recognising external montitors at all:

```
Cobrakai$xrandr  --verbose --screen 1
Invalid screen number 1 (display has 1)
```

Whereas it works fine for screen 0 (my native screen)

```
Cobrakai$xrandr  --screen 0
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 2304 x 1824, maximum 2304 x 1846
default connected 2304x1824+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x800       60.0      2.0  
   1152x720       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   1024x640       60.0  
   800x600        60.0  
   800x500        60.0  
   640x480        60.0  
   720x480        60.0  
   1280x778        1.0  
   1280x1824       1.0  
   1280x1846       2.0  
   2304x1824       1.0* 
   2304x1846       2.0  
Cobrakai$
```

Even when other applications can tell that there are many screens (per screenshot) - how do I get xrandr to recognise the additional screens?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that at least part of the problem is that the Xrandr utility is designed only to deal with X11 windows and not native osx screens...